# angular 2 google.maps.places without map

Tags: google-maps, angular, google-maps-api-3, ionic2

I'm trying to get place details using place_id without having a map canvas. It appears that making a "http.get" call to the api itself wont work, but instead forced to use the angular google maps implementation.

currently stack on:

```
let service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally managed to find the answer by looking at jquery examples. Turned out to be a pretty simple process by using a dummy dom div

> document.createElement('div')

```
  let service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));
  service.getDetails({ placeId: placeId}, function(place, status){              
    console.log(JSON.stringify(place));
  });
```

For example to get photos associated with place just loop of over the "photos" object array by using the getUrl method, see below (use your desired size):

> place.photos[1].getUrl({'maxWidth': 100, 'maxHeight': 100})

Other available properties here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places